# Symbolizing Isochrones in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, symbology, visualisation, isochrone

I have generated isochrones for London based on my parameters.

However, the isochrones by definition are overlapping polygons.

I would like to show the different polygons of the isochrones using different colors.

I have tried using gradient symbology, but the desired effect is not there since the overlapping polygons are making the different colors interact with each other.

I can separate the polygons into different files and then subtract each polygon from the others so that they don't overlap.

However, since I am relatively new to QGIS, I am wondering whether there is an alternate simpler way to achieve this visual effect?

I am using QGIS 3.4.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Union tool to get rid of the overlapping polygons and then add the colors you want to each polygon. Union tool is located under `Vector -> Geoprocessing tools -> Union`.

[image]

But if the overlapping polygons are located in one layer, then it is better to use v.clean tool under `Processing toolbox -> GRASS GIS 7 commands -> Vector -> v.clean`, and under Cleaning tool use `Break`, as you can see below:

[image]

In QGIS 3.4.1 it is under `GRASS -> Vector -> v.clean` and break is located under the cleaning tool:

[image]

It will remove overlapping polygons located in one polygon layer.

Comment: I am using QGIS v3.4.1 and I cannot see the parameter called 'Cleaning tool' inside the v.clean interface

Comment: @DotPi I updated the answer considering QGIS 3.4.1. It is better to mention QGIS version in your question.

Comment: Updated Question. It works now.